# How to create a user using code when i am using devise gem for Sign up / Sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise gem for my application.
Now i would like to create a user using code, but in the database table "users" 
the password is encrypted. So i hope i cannot directly save it as

```
 
 new_user = User.new
 new_user.email = "xyz@xys.com"
 new_user.password = "1sdf" - i cannot use this becs its actually : encrypted_password
 new_user.save
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try it? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No.. I checked it and its working, now i know Rails Devise is more smarter...!!
However i missed the :password_confirmation field when i was testing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this actually, devise's encrypted_password method will handle encrypting the password you pass in and storing it in the database

```
u = User.new(:email => "foo@bar.com", :password => '1sdf', :password_confirmation =>       '1sdf')
u.save
```

Try it out in the rails console.